# In GitHub I closed a bad pull request, but it closed my branch as well, how to fix?

Tags: github, git-branch

We have a three tiered branch structure, Master, Integration, and Development. A user inappropriately put in a Pull request from Development to Master. We never do this, and our rules caught it and didn't let it proceed. So far so good. I then went in and closed the pull request.

Now I find a big red 'CLOSED' button next to my development branch. We didn't want to close out the branch, just the bad pull request. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'm hoping I'm misinterpreting the graphic being there, and it only signifies that the last request was closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your repository's `Branches` page. If you're seeing the `CLOSED` graphic next to your development branch under `Active Branches`, then yes your branch still exists but the most-recent pull request against it is closed (like you said).

On the other hand, if your development branch doesn't exist anymore, you won't see it appear on your `Branches` page at all.